# Иконки для каждого пункта меню Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

Ребят, есть такая тема, есть меню в котором для каждого пункта меню есть иконки для этого я написал следующие

```html
<?if (!defined( "B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>
  <?if (!empty($arResult)):?>
    <div class="container myAsideMenu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <aside>
            <span class="title-menu">КАТАЛОГ</span>
            <ul id="scrollMenu">
              <? foreach($arResult as $arItem): if($arParams[ "MAX_LEVEL"]==1 && $arItem[ "DEPTH_LEVEL"]>1) continue; ?>
              <?if($arItem[ "SELECTED"]):?>
                <li>
                  <a href="<?=$arItem[" LINK "]?>" class="selected">
                    <?=$arItem[ "TEXT"]?>
                      <img src="<?=$arItem[" PARAMS "]["IMG "]?>" border="0" />
                  </a>
                </li>
                <?else:?>
                  <li>
                    <a href="<?=$arItem[" LINK "]?>">
                      <?=$arItem[ "TEXT"]?>
                        <img src="<?=$arItem[" PARAMS "]["IMG "]?>" border="0" />
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <?endif?>

                    <?endforeach?>
            </ul>
          </aside>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?endif?>
```

Но место картинок в инспекторе кода добавилась строчка `<img src="" border="0">.` Почему-то путь к картинке пустой, хотя в расширенном редакторе меню прописал для одного из пунктов следующий путь /bitrix/templates/shablon/images/arrayBottom.png

Comment: а откуда тянется картинка?

Answer (score 1):

Собственно решил вопрос тем, что в расширенном режиме прописал параметр IMG